# How to get sleep settings on Hololens 2?

Tags: hololens

I need to change sleep settings on Hololens 2, but on Device portal there are an empty page on sleep settings tool.  All updates were installed, all other tools work fine. Could you help, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUwtg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Sleep Setting is under the System > Preferences page. if you want to add this tool to the workspace, please select the Preferences tool. More information please see: [Device Portal Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-windows-device-portal#home)

Comment: Yes, I know, but on Sleep Settings no data, it is en empty page. Please look the screenshot in the topic message. Don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Screenshot is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUwtg.png

Comment: The Sleep Setting tool is obsoleted and instead of provided as an independent tool, it integrated into the Preferences tool. It should be a historical legacy which can be added to the workspace.